# My webcam doesn't work, how to set it up?

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, webcam, hardware-failure

I just recently bought a third hand Dell Inspiron m5030 laptop, running Windows 7. The problem is, Windows can't seem to use my webcam, even though it is listed in Device Manager as "Integrated Camera". Right-clicking and checking the properties shows me "installed and working properly", but no application is able to use the camera.

Why is it happening and how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Have you installed all drivers that came with the laptop? Do you have any webcam software?

Answer (score 0):

According to what you say, means that you are **missing** the driver, so try doing a search on the OS and see what driver is missing.. try this [tool](http://www.drivereasy.com/) wich detects which drivers are needed and then he downloads from the Internet, and you also have the possibility to update the drivers installed